# Wicket - Passing PageParameters through LoginPage

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

What I'm trying to do is a simple page that gets one parameter which is an *id* of an object.

```
    @MountPath("share/${share_id}")
    public class IndexPage extends WebPage
    {
            public IndexPage(PageParameters parameters)
            {
                    String id = parameters.get("share_id").toString();
                    // etc...
            }
    }
```

This page has to be secured from unauthorised visits. I've added *@AuthorizeInstantiation("user")* annotation and managed standard Wicket security support including *getSignInPageClass()* in *MainApplication* that extends *AuthenticatedWebApplication*.

The problem is when I need to get back to my *IndexPage* after authorization **with original parameters**. I got some solution but I need it to be more elegant and more common (universal).

1. Override *restartResponseAtSignInPage()* method in Application class
2. Retrieve parameters from *RequestCycle*:

   ```
   final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
   PageParametersEncoder encoder = new PageParametersEncoder();
   PageParameters parameters = encoder.decodePageParameters(request.getUrl());
   ```
3. Pass them by throwing *new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(getSignInPageClass(), newParameters);*

I know it's not a nice solution because I need to be sure what is exact index of parameter in my url (encoder returns only indexedParameters, not namedParameters - or I am doing sth wrong?).

Maybe there is somebody that has met that problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Siginpage, after you have verified the login, make a call to `continueToOriginalDestination();`

This should do the trick.